# Android studio 3.1.2 : Can't Able to run and debug application

Tags: android, ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YscJG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u91HE.png)

About Mac : MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012),
version : 10.13.2, 
Android studio version : 3.1.2

Hey guys as you can see in image ADB is detecting the device but device is not getting displayed on "Select Deployment Target".
I have tried other solutions present in internet like : "use libusb backend" etc.

please let me know guys How to solve this issue.

And some interesting things:

For Android studio version : 3.0.1
I was able to see devices and can run but can't able to debug.

For below version from 3.0.1:
Devices are getting detected and able to run and debug.

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion and what is the device OS version?

Comment: minSdk : 15, targetDeviceSDK : 26, device OS : 26

Comment: Late reply but I got the solution. Using MacOS, I killed all adb process from activity monitor and that's it. Everything is fine now